# Device in use, but not mounted

Tags: usb, ssd, fsck, unmounting

After plugging in a USB attached SATA SSD, `fsck` tells me that
this device is in use. But it is not mounted at all. What's
happening here? And how can I `fsck` this device?

Here are some information after plugging in the device:

```
$ dmesg 
[725329.424635] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[725329.446411] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=1561
[725329.446420] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[725329.446426] usb 2-1: Product: SABRENT
[725329.446431] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: SABRENT
[725329.446435] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: DB9876543214E
[725329.452809] scsi host3: uas
[725329.453928] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SABRENT                   0204 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[725329.455721] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[725329.967206] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[725329.967215] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[725329.967362] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[725329.967368] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[725329.967733] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[725329.968079] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[725330.238773]  sdc: sdc1
[725330.240931] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[725330.440904] EXT4-fs (sdc1): recovery complete
[725330.440907] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with writeback data mode. Opts: (null)
```

```
$ lsblk -fs /dev/sdc1
NAME  FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdc1  ext4         921e806c-1ccc-4427-9b4d-5e474832395a 
└─sdc
```

```
$ fsck.ext4 /dev/sdc1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sdc1 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

**Update:**

```
$ lsof /dev/ | grep sdc
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

Comment: Can you use the '''mount'''' command and share the output?

Comment: @HeysusEscobar I can mount the device without any problems. `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc1 /media/test` does not return any error message. And the device seems to be working ok.

Comment: Please update the question with output of `lsof /dev/ | grep sdc`

Comment: @Andreas by running the command 'mount' without options it will display all the mounted filesystems, this information may be useful to troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

in my case, mount command didn't show that device, but there was a docker container running with the mounded target directory bound as a volume.

if you running docker, it would be worth to try this

```
docker ps -q | xargs -I {} docker container inspect -f '{{ printf "{}" }}{{ .Name }} {{printf "\n"}}{{ .HostConfig.Binds }}' {}
```

and find the mounted directory and try to stop that container

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried editing fstab.

Partitions listed in `etc/fstab` can be configured to automatically mount during the boot process.

The syntax of fstab entry should look like this:

```
<file system>    <dir>      <type>  <options>             <dump> <pass>

/dev/sdc1        /etc/test  ext4    defaults              1      2
```

Be sure to logout/restart. Hope this helps.

Comment: How would this possibly address the issue here? This is not helpful